# How to use JS variable inside HTML attribute value

Tags: javascript, html

I want to write `JavaScript` code and to use it in `Python+Selenium` script. Target `URL` is [Microsoft account login page](https://login.live.com/login.srf?&wreply=https%3A%2F%2Foutlook.live.com%2Fowa%2F%3Fnlp%3D1%26realm%3Dlogin.live.com). Here I want to force onclick opening `Terms of use` page not in new tab, but in new window so I made some changes to appropriate anchor tag. I have a little experience in `JS`, so this is what I got for now:

```
document.querySelector('a#ftrTerms').setAttribute("onclick", "window.open('https://login.live.com/gls.srf?urlID=WinLiveTermsOfUse&mkt=EN-US&vv=1600', '', 'width=800,height=600')")
document.querySelector('a#ftrTerms').removeAttribute('href')
```

...and this works fine (not the best way, but it's ok). However, redirection `URL` is hardcoded, so I use following to get `URL` from `href` first and then pass it to attribute:

```
var reference = document.querySelector('a#ftrTerms').getAttribute('href');
document.querySelector('a#ftrTerms').setAttribute("onclick", "window.open(\'' + reference +  '\', '', 'width=800,height=600')")
document.querySelector('a#ftrTerms').removeAttribute('href')
```

...and this code is not working: my attribute in `HTML` appears like

`onclick="window.open('' + reference +  '', '', 'width=800,height=600')"`.

So how to substitute `reference` name with its actual value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to calculate the string from the value:

```
document.querySelector('a#ftrTerms').setAttribute("onclick", "window.open('" + reference + "', '', 'width=800,height=600')")
```

`reference` should not be in the string, but concatenated with the rest of the string prefix and suffix